# Page not found (404) Request Method:

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

please help me. I don't know why can't see the detail of product when i click a product. both first list work good just when i need to see detail of product in second list(filtered list) an 404 error shows.
thanks

here is my code below:

my urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'shop'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('categories/<category>/', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='product-list'),
    path('categories/<int:pk>/', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product-detail'),
]
```

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, get_list_or_404
from django.views import generic
from .models import Category, Product


class HomeView(generic.ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'home.html'


class ProductListView(generic.ListView):

    template_name = 'product_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, title=self.kwargs['category'])
        return Product.objects.filter(category=self.category)


class ProductDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product_detail.html'
```

product_list.html

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
    Welcome | Global Market
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}


{% for product in product_list %}
<a href="{% url 'shop:product-detail' product.pk %}">
    <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header">{{ product.title }}</div>
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="{{ product.title }}">
        <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">{{ product.description }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

product_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
    Welcome | Global Market
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>thid</h1>

{{ product.name }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback.

Comment: this is the traceback from browser: 
Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/1/
Raised by:  shop.views.ProductListView

No Category matches the given query.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
and from my terminal:  this shows-- Not Found: /favicon.ico
Not Found: /categories/1/
[13/Nov/2020 23:46:25] "GET /categories/1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1745

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the you visit `/categories/1`, it will use the `ProductListView`, since the `str` path converter also accepts a sequence of digits. You can swap the paths, so:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'shop'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('categories/<int:pk>/', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product-detail'),
    path('categories/<category>/', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='product-list'),
]
```

Then for `/categories/1`, it will match with `<int:pk>` as `1`, and thus fire the `ProductDetailView`.